# How to Target WPF child controls with nested styles by name?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, app.xaml

I am experimenting with creating a custom button in WPF.

I have basic XAML for a `Button`, with two `TextBlock` controls inside the button. One will be an image rendered by FontAwesome, and one will be text.

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource mediumLabel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4">SETTINGS</TextBlock>
<Button  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource mainButton}" Template="{DynamicResource mainButtonTemplate}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Image" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">cogs</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Label" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="SETTINGS" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

I have global styles defined in `App.xaml`.

I can target each of these three elements individually, with individual styles in my `App.xaml`.

What I would like to do, I guess just for organization and ease of future use, I want to have a style for the `Button`, with nested styles to target each of the two `TextBlock` controls. Each will be styled differently, so I cant target the `TextBlock` type. I want to reference them by name.

I have tried referencing the main `control_name.childcontrol_name`, as well as just the control name.

I can't seem to get enough info on how to do this when searching, as I might be searching for the wrong terminology...

My Attempt at the nested style, with two attempts for the nested styles targeting.

```
<Style x:Key="mainButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Reference Image}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Genesis_desktop;component/tools/fontawesome-free-5.15.1-desktop/otfs/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="ForeGround" Value="orange"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Reference mainButton.Label}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking the wrong way. It's not the `Style` that searches its target. It's the target that searches its `Style`.
The XAML parser creates an instance of the markup object e.g. a `<TextBlock>` and then, after checking the local `FrameworkElement.Style` property, traverses the logical tree to find if there is somewhere a `Style` defined that targets this instantiated type or that has a key, that matches the requested resource key.

What you want would be also quite inefficient as the name inside a namescope must be unique and namescopes are always quite "small". Such a element name driven mapping would require an explicit style that only matches a single control. And it would require to know the name of this control in advance.
This means you, the author of this individual Style, have direct access to the named control.
You could therefore define the style directly in the local `ResourceDictionary` e.g. `TextBlock.Resources`.
This has the same effect: the `Style` now applies to a single `TextBlock` element, that you know by name.

If you need to declare the exclusive style on a different parent `ResourceDictionary` or as merge resource, you usually name the `Style` by applying the `x:Key` directive and then request this resource explicitly e.g. by using `StaticResource` markup extension.

Also `x:Reference` returns a name and not a `Type`. The `TargetType` property is of type `Type`. This property uses a `TypeConverter`, which allows to assign a string value which is then converted to `Type`.

What you want is not possible by default. Styles are pure type specific (when defined as implicit resource) or are mapped explicitly by their `x:Key` value (as additional constraint). On the other hand, what you want is already there in a different form and can be achieved by using local resources or the `x:Key`directive together with the `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` markup extension.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your style is that the *nested* styles are defined in its `Resources`. These can only be accessed in the scope of this style. Consequently, the button cannot, because it has a different scope.

I do not think that it is possible to nest styles this way, but you could alternatively create a `DataTemplate` for the `Content` of the button and nest the styles there. Assign a key to them and reference them from your `TextBlock`s. In your `mainButton` style, you can add a setter to set the `ContentTemplate` to this template. You could also set the `ContentTemplate` on your button explicitly (but this would mean you have to move the data template out of the style). I hope this is the kind of nesting or encapsulation that you wanted to achive.

```
<Style x:Key="mainButton" TargetType="Button">
   <Style.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="MyButtoDataTemplate">
         <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
               <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Genesis_desktop;component/tools/fontawesome-free-5.15.1-desktop/otfs/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid"/>
               <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="14"/>
               <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
               <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="orange"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
               <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="14"/>
               <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
               <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
         </DataTemplate.Resources>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="Image" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}">cogs</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Label" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" Text="SETTINGS" />
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Style.Resources>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
   <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="14"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
   <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyButtoDataTemplate}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Your `Button` definition is simplified to this, as the style already defines everything:

```
<Button  Grid.Column="1"
         Grid.Row="5"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         Style="{DynamicResource mainButton}"
         Template="{DynamicResource mainButtonTemplate}"/>
```